# Set JQuery HTML javascript Checkbox working but not showing as checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

All im trying to do is check if a checkbox is checked, if so, uncheck it.
The checkbox is being set properly but not showing as checked. I have check this my putting a checkbox outside the `<li>` and it works fine

Here is my current HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html manifest="cache.manifest">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Events.js"></script>

        |<script src="Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
        </style>

        <!--Progress Bar Scripts-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

        <script>
            function selectAll() {
                if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
                    alert("checked");
                    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
                }
                else {
                    alert("unchecked");
                    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
                        </script>
    </head>
<div data-role="page" id="selectProducts" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <div style="width: auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:1em">
                    <label for="subtotal" style=" display: inline-block; padding-right: 7em; font-weight: bold">Total:</label>
                    <label id="subtotal"></label>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float:right">
                   <!-- <a id="checkAll" href="javascript:selectAll()" data-role="button" style="width: 200px;">Remove Selection</a>-->
                    <input onclick="selectAll()" type="button" id="checkAll" value="Check All" /> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="isChkd" value="true" /> 
                </div>

                <label style="padding-bottom:8em"></label>

            </div>
            <label for="contactShow" style=" display: inline-block; padding-right: 5em; font-weight: bold">Contact: </label>
            <label id="contactShow">Alex Turner</label><br />

            <label for="contactIdShow" style=" display: inline-block; padding-right: 5em; font-weight: bold">Cus Ref: </label>
            <label id="contactIdShow">12345</label><br />



            <ul id="OrderList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">

                <li data-role="list-divider">Order Details</li>

                <li>
            <a href="#" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                <label style="border-top-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;" data-corners="false">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxProd" id="checkboxProd2" data-theme="c" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="checkboxProd2" style="border-top-width: 0px; margin-top: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
                            <h3>Black Denim</h3>
                        </label>


                        <table id="OrderDetailsTable2" border="0" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; color: transparent; width: 250px; font-size: small; padding: 0; padding-left: 3em;">
                        </table>

                    </fieldset>
                </label>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
            <div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float:right">
                    <a href="#searchProducts" data-role="button" style="width: 200px;">Add To Order</a>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Note that a LI can only be a child of an UL, and a button can not be a direct child of a UL ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/aYcNV/

Comment: Seems to be working fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/cDt4E/

Comment: No Errors no but ive tried it within different positions within the <li> and it seems it works until the fieldset

Comment: there is an error for fieldset, it needs a legend, would that affect it?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AmA8N/)**

Try this

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 

    <script>  
    function selectAll()
        {
            if ($('#checkboxProd2').is(':checked'))
            {
                alert("checked");
               $('#checkboxProd2').prop('checked', false);
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("unchecked");
               $('#checkboxProd2').prop('checked', true); 
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: sorry, didnt work, stops working I think in the HTML when it gets within the fieldset

Comment: its because you put it inside $(document).ready(function(), put function 'selectAll()' outside $(document).ready

Comment: Have you appended <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script> in your head tag

Comment: @user2681625 yes you should first append it,try the updated code

Comment: The above code will work for sure,unless your remaining code has error

Comment: added to original post @SarathSprakash

Comment: append the above code immediately after the <head> tag , after that your other scripts and all

Comment: tried that. I have minimised my code down enough to identify that this is jquery mobile going wrong on the input going in the label. Still not resolved